# How prevent duplicates in SQL DW with no Primary Keys?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage, azure-synapse

SQL DW does not support Primary Keys or Surrogate Keys or UNIQUE.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-tables-overview

How would I be able to prevent duplicate rows? From what I can tell the one supported option `IDENTITY` does not prevent this, it simply inserts a unique `INT` value in a column for each row.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.T1
(   
    C1 INT IDENTITY(1,1)    NOT NULL,
    C2 VARCHAR(30)              NULL
)
WITH
(   DISTRIBUTION = HASH(C2),
    CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX
);

INSERT INTO dbo.T1 VALUES (NULL);    
INSERT INTO dbo.T1 VALUES (NULL);

-- You will see two rows
SELECT * FROM dbo.T1;
```

Comment: you can use a ranking function or a flavor of it.

Comment: @junketsu How would that work? Can you please give an example?

Comment: gave you an answer below. I changed it to temp tables to game up the data. Dont want to create logs creating dbo tables and then deleting ; dropping them.

Comment: `SELECT MAX(c1), c2 FROM dbo.T1 GROUP BY c2`

Answer (score 1):

You prevent duplicate rows by checking that the value does not already exist.

In general, in a data warehouse, you are moving batches of data from one table to another.

Let's assume that I have two tables, name src and dst:

```
src (code,desc)
dst (code,desc)
```

I want to append rows from src to dst, only if the code does not already exist in dst.

A typical way to do this is with a NOT EXISTS clause:

```
insert into dst
select s.code, s.dest
from   src s
where not exists (
       select 1
       from   dest d
       where  d.code = s.code);
```

If you wanted the combination of code and desc to be unique, just extend the WHERE clause:

```
insert into dst
select s.code, s.dest
from   src s
where not exists (
       select 1
       from   dest d
       where  d.code = s.code
              and d.desc = s.desc);
```

Because you're using Azure SQL Data Warehouse there is a chance you're going to want to do this to a clustered columnstore index. Take note of the documentation around batch sizes. If your batches are small you could get bad quality indexes and poor performance. In this case use a CTAS algorithm to recreate the dimension, or use a HEAP table instead of the CCI.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-best-practices#optimize-clustered-columnstore-tables

Comment: Thank you. What about locking? Our inserts will be done asynchronously with multiple streams coming in simultaneously. Is there anything we can do to ensure we don't get duplicates in that situation?

Comment: Where are your streams coming from? A better pattern might be to micro-batch the streams through event hub / Databricks, then load the micro batches via Polybase.

Comment: What you really don't want to do is connect multiple processes to the DW, each writing single row inserts. Your performance will be poor in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Check blow

```
CREATE TABLE #T1
(   
    C1 INT IDENTITY(1,1)    NOT NULL,
    C2 VARCHAR(30)              NULL
)
--WITH
--(   DISTRIBUTION = HASH(C2),
--    CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX
--);

INSERT INTO #T1 VALUES (NULL);    
INSERT INTO #T1 VALUES (NULL);

select *
from (
select *
,Rank_1 = row_number() over(partition by Check_1 order by C1)
from (
SELECT *
--,Rank_1 = row_number() over(partition by C1 order by C1)
,Check_1 = case when isnull(C2,'N/A') = 'N/A' then 'DupVals' else 'Non-DupVals' end
FROM #T1
) a
)b
where Rank_1 = 1
;
```

Comment: This doesn't prevent duplicates. It ignores them in a query, but that query would be super slow as well.

Comment: well your going DW route; I'm hoping your initial and then only incremental loading. And perhaps data like so should be kept in a seperate table for QA. You can always re-insert such data once its cleaned up. I do not know your full bizz logic.